# post data to a popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-post

How can I use Javascript/jQuery to post to a popup-window?

```
var eids = selected_Ids.join();
var url =  'http://www.zyx.com';
$.post (url, {
    eId : eids
},
function (data) {
    // newpage = result;
    var new_window = window.open(url,  "abc");
});
```

The popup doesn't appear. what am i doing wrong.

Comment: You want to do what now ?

Comment: what is the point of having window.open in $post function ?

Comment: I need to open a popup window and post data to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function formPost(actionUrl, a) {
        var sHTML = "<form id='form1' action='" + actionUrl + "' method='post'>";

        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i = i + 2) {
            sHTML += "<input name='" + a[i] + "' type='hidden' value='" + a[i + 1] + "' />";
        }

        sHTML += "</form>";
        var ooo = window.open("", "test");
        ooo.document.body.innerHTML = sHTML;
        ooo.form1.submit();
    }
```

just call this function

```
formPost('http://www.zyx.com', ["key1", "111", "key2", "222"])
```

it work fine in IE and Chrome

enjoy it~ :)

Comment: This opens a new tab but not a popup.